# Attempting to install Linux in BIOS mode but there's no option whether to boot in UEFI or BIOS mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, uefi

I am trying to install Solus or Ubuntu onto an Acer Aspire V5-531 as Windows is painfully slow but I don't want any data to be deleted. The Setup menu is painfully simple and the system came with Win 7 installed in BIOS mode which is where the issue is coming from. I've tried using Live DVDs and USB devices but there isn't any option to not boot into BIOS mode. Is it possible to force Solus or Ubuntu to boot into BIOS mode? I would also like to note that I am aware of the Ubuntu Live CD but I would prefer to install Solus if possible. I can't seem to upload images but I do have some of the Setup menus if anyone would like to see them

Comment: Maybe the firmware has CSM disabled? I'd instead look into converting Windows to UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no operating system will let you choose whether to boot into BIOS or UEFI mode. But you can choose between those options by entering BIOS when your laptop boots up.

[This thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519610/allowing-boot-of-ubuntu-on-a-acer-aspire-v5-531-with-uefi) implies that both modes should be available for your machine. Since it's an Acer laptop, I guess you can enter BIOS by pressing the F2 key a few seconds after pressing the power button. If that key does not work, you can try FN+F2, Shift+F2, ESC, DEL keys, but I'm pretty sure F2 will work for you.

Also, most Linux distributions will allow you to install the operation system on both BIOS or UEFI mode, as you prefer. Ergo, your laptop being in BIOS mode is no problem if your goal is just to install Linux. In order to receive further assistance with your setup, you need to tell us, which installation mode you prefer, and if you plan to change the Win7 installation from BIOS to UEFI, and if you want to be able to quickly switch between those two operating systems without entering BIOS.